# Windows 10 ethernet not working; Windows troubleshooter says modem issue

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, desktop

My wife's Windows 10 desktop has been having intermittent issues with the wired Ethernet lately where nothing loads, pings fail, and eventually it "just works" again some time later. I've ruled out the network card being bad as booting a Live Linux worked fine and upon returning to Windows it didn't work again. Chrome has a heart attack when run in this state where it opens windows and never responds. Other applications just time out and say they can't connect.

Windows troubleshooter says that there's an issue connecting to the modem, but the Linux test already ruled out the hardware being an issue.

Computer has a valid DHCP configuration for the network. Static configuration makes no difference.

Virus scan is clean with up to date (as of June 3) virus definitions. All drivers are up to date. Device details page says it's working properly.

All Windows updates installed successfully. Sfc /scannow already been run with no issues.

No errors in Windows event log.

I've tried the network stack reset, disabled all firewalls, and it works in safe mode with the same driver. What else can I look at?

## Edit June 20:

I have reinstalled Windows 10 with nothing but basic usability drivers (graphics, mouse/keyboard, network) and it still happens. Using LatencyMon I have found that when the issue occurs there are large delays within ndis.sys. If I unplug the Ethernet cable the latency goes back down to nearly zero. I found an old Wireless-G USB adapter and when I use it with no Ethernet, I get usable (at G speed) connection.

My wife has informed me that this issue started after purchasing our new router. Literally every other device in the house works fine (another desktop, laptop, four phones, XboxOne, Wii U, three 3DSs, Chromecast, SmartTV, etc). The Router is a Belkin AC1600 and the NIC is an onboard Intel 82579V. Default Ethernet settings on router and NIC.

Comment: This is a little too broad to know exactly what to have you do. Sounds specific to Windows 10 though, so I'd suggest you first verify the computer is clean of viruses and malware. Then follow the steps in this Microsoft Support article to see if it resolves the issue - [Fix network connection issues](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/fix-network-connection-issues) (yes, I realize you have already done some of it). Update your question if it still is having issues.

Comment: I've already tried all the things listed on that page incidentally. I realize my question is broad but I'm looking for any test I can try that I haven't already.

Comment: What about malware? All Windows Updates installed? You can try running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt. Also, you can go to `msconfig` and disable startup items to see if it works then. If it does, start enabling items one at a time until you find what is causing the issue.

Comment: Do you have any restore points you can try? In case you have a broken Windows Update ...

Comment: I'll check for a restore point later. Unfortunately it's bed time now.

Comment: Did you install the manufacturer's software (i.e control software, not drivers) for the NIC card? If so, try uninstalling it. If that removes the drivers as well, let Windows install its own drivers. The fact that it works in safe mode points to something in the startup list.

Comment: It's using Microsoft's driver.

Comment: since you have access to a live linux media, how about doing a [virus scan](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167539/how-do-i-scan-my-windows-partition-for-viruses-from-ubuntu) from there?

Comment: I can try it, but I trust the virus definitions used by the AV already working on Windows.